# SQL byte[] Parameters

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I want to INSERT a byte array into a table (using C#). I've seen this: [SqlParameterCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5xwx8sc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  but I can't figure out how to use it - it doesn't seem to have a `value` parameter like [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  does. (Perhaps there's some way to use `AddWithValue` with byte arrays?)

And the same goes for a SELECT - I want to SELECT a row WHERE ColumnX = MyByteArray. (The column contains `binary`).

So how is it done?

Comment: Possible duplication (there is code example there) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955977/insert-binary-data-into-sql-from-c-sharp-without-a-stored-procedure

Comment: Virtually exact duplicate of the above link.

Comment: @cvraman Thanks. I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: Ha. Now that it's closed - SO doesn't allow me to delete my question.

Comment: @ispiro : Was my comment deleted or what ?

Comment: @cvraman I don't know. Maybe when a post gets closed as a duplicate, they remove the original suggestion for it? (Though I don't think so.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use paramete datatype VarBinary

```
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@ArrayValues", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 100).Value = YourArrayList;
```